# ls LINQ an ORM (Object Relational Mapper)?

Tags: linq, orm

Is LINQ an ORM ?

I've heard a lot of people say LINQ follows the rules of an Object Relation Mapper. But I don't understand; is this true?

Comment: LINQ is just a *base technology* in .NET. *Linq-to-SQL* is a "demo implementation" of a SQL Server-only ORM using LINQ to query its data

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LINQ is a C#/VB.NET language syntax and a set of method signatures for querying data.

There are many providers for this syntax and some of them are ORMs. The simplest case is when you are querying collections in memory which is not an ORM. There are also ways to query XML, Active Directory and many others which are not ORMs using the same syntax and the same set of methods (implemented differently).

Practically every serious .NET ORM technology has some level of LINQ support

LINQ to SQL is the first ORM to support LINQ and it was kind of a proof of concept. It is easy to learn and lightweight but lacks a lot of features. It is still pretty decent and Stack Overflow used it (I'm not sure if they still use it).
Entity Framework has LINQ to Entities provider and it is the heavy hitter from Microsoft.
NHibernate has a LINQ provider that in my opinion barely works but they may fix it some day

There are more ORMs out there and most of them have some level of LINQ support.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to call LINQ to SQL a proof of concept. In that sense I think the first version of the Entity Framework was more a proof of concept than LINQ to SQL is.

Comment: I didn't mean that it is a proof of concept in the sense that it is not useful. I love LINQ to SQL. My point was that it demonstrated that you can build a LINQ provider on top of an ORM.

Comment: With that I completely agree. I even [described this three years back](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=42). Without LINQ to SQL, *"the C# team would have a hard time evangelizing LINQ."*.

Comment: FWIW, even Matt Warren (the architect for LINQ to SQL) admitted that it "was never even supposed to exist." [Read More](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/05/31/the-origin-of-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

Ok people, repeat after me:

***[LINQ is NOT about working with databases.](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/LINQ-is-not-about-working-with-databases.aspx)***

LINQ is an abstraction layer for working with data which allows for set based operations, projections, filters, etc on anything that can be enumerated over. It just happens to have providers for working with relational data (LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Datasets, LINQ to Entities).

Answer (score 9):

> Is the LINQ ORM ?

No.  Linq is not itself an ORM.

This code uses Linq to Objects, which is still valid Linq:

```
var someData = new int[] { 5, 3, 2, 7, 4 };
var someResults = someData
    .OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .Take(3)
    ;
```

And here is some Linq to XML code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> partNos =
    from item in purchaseOrder.Descendants("Item")
    where (int) item.Element("Quantity") *
        (decimal) item.Element("USPrice") > 100
    orderby (string)item.Element("PartNumber")
    select item;
```

Neither of these code samples have anything to do with [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), since they don't map objects, nor do they work with relational databases.

Linq has been used with some ORM technologies though:

- Linq to Entities allows you to access the Entity Framework ORM with Linq.
- Linq to NHibernate does the same for NHibernate.

You can find out how Linq itself works by checking out this library and the associated articles.  They deal with Linq to Objects, but will give you the basis of how Linq itself works:

http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/

It will show you that Linq need not have anything to do with an ORM.

Comment: I disagree that extension methods are LINQ, because that isn't *language integrated querying*. Your second example is LINQ imo.

Comment: @Steven: Nope, they're still considered part of Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx - even if "language integrated query" is a misnomer, it still is under the same umbrella.  I personally find the query syntax poorer in all cases so far except joins and lets :)  Though that part is just my opinion.

Comment: The article describes that there are extension methods for enabling LINQ, but that doesn't mean these extension method *are* LINQ. But perhaps I'm just nitpicking ;-). I'm on the other side of the spectrum. I tend to prevent using LINQ extension methods except for very simple things. I've found that code gets much more readable when using LINQ queries.

Comment: @Steven: Lol.  From different worlds, you and I :)  I admit that joins and lets are downright impossible to do cleanly without query syntax.  But I personally understand Linq as a generator/filter/transform rather than as a query.  Both models are correct, which is why they support both forms.

Comment: They're both good approaches, I agree. I carefully pick one on a case by case basis. There is absolutely no single correct way of doing things, as long as everybody is doing things my way ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If we were to go by the wiki defiinition of the term Object-Relational Mapping,

***Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping) in computer software is a programming technique for converting data between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming languages. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that can be used from within the programming language. There are both free and commercial packages available that perform object-relational mapping, although some programmers opt to create their own ORM tools.***
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

then yes, LINQ is an ORM in the sense that it is a programming technique for converting(and querying) data between incompatible systems in object-oriented programming languages, creating, in effect, a "virtual object database" that can be used from within the programming language.

Comment: Lo and behold, LINQ is in fact listed as an ORM on the wiki list of ORMs. . . List_of_object-relational_mapping_software .

Comment: LINQ can be used on database tables the same way it can be used on enumerations, but it's a bit of a stretch to refer to objects in memory as a "virtual object database". LINQ is not converting data between incompatible type systems, because it's part of the same language from which the data comes.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ is Language Intergrated Query and is NOT an ORM.
It can be used as query layer on top of an ORM product like Entity Framework or Telerik Open Access or NHibernate.
ORM is as you say Object Relation Mapper - it does mapping between entities in the database layer to entities into your Object Oriented code - classes that represent the database in your application.
For further discussion see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193781/164906).